# A graph with 20 edges has 5 vertices of degree 5 with the rest of degree 4. How many vertices of each degree does it have?

Tags: graph-theory

Actually, I have an answer and it is pretty simple to be obtained. You just have to use the classical theorem that states that the sum of all degrees of the graph is equal twice the number of edges. In this case, G(u) = all degrees of the vertices of the graph.

You get something like this: Sum of G(u) = 2E, so you just have to do write the numbers at the expected places and you'll get a result.

But this operation in particular will always give you a decimal number, which makes no sense, half vertex does not exist. (I applied the same formula to similar problems and I could find a solution that makes sense)

Here comes the real problem; **there's a theorem proving that the number of vertices with odd degree in a graph is always even**. However, the description of the problem provides 5 vertices with degree 5. Thus, such graph does not exist, it can't be graphically represented. Or there is a possible solution?

My professor is sure that there is, maybe he didn't notice the "5 vertices of degree 5".

Comment: As you are saying. There cannot be a graph with an odd number of odd degrees.

Comment: You need consider the vertices of degree 3 and 1 as well

Comment: @E.O. he said that there remaining vertices are of degree 4.

Comment: @DanielMontealegre my bad

Comment: The only thing to consider is loops. I think that some textbooks count the loops for a total degree of $1$, but then handshaking lemma is not true anymore.